# How to use watin in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, watin

I have found a lot of information about how to use it in a classical program (console). Also how to use it for tests.

But how to use it in the real life?
I would like to use Watin for autologin users in a iframe when they clic a button.

I use ASP.NET MVC4.5.

What should I do?

Comment: Since Watin is for automating the browser, I don't think your question is clear enough to answer. What are you trying to achieve by manipulating a web browser from a web server?

Comment: You are right. Maybe I am doing it wroing. I want to enter to a website, make some clics, and redirect the output to the client. What I want is website that sends credentials to another external one.

Comment: This sounds closer to the purpose of tools like Mechanize, which has ports for Ruby, Python and Perl; the downside is that it won't work if the page you are manipulating depends heavily on JavaScript that you can't simulate using other means. You could potentially use IronRuby or IronPython to call out to Mechanize. But WatiN doesn't make a whole lot of sense, unless you have extremely small numbers of simultaneous users (like 1).

Comment: "What shoul I do" - You should not do that...as normal browsers are not exactly happy to run in sessions not associated with interative user... But you will have a lot of fun trying to make it work.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's exactly what watin is for. I've used it for ASP.NET apps very effectively.

Comment: @DanVallejo - you run watin against regular browser from IIS (which runs in non-interactive session)? Note that this question is about server side automation of browser, not "run watin with browser on my desktop in interactive session to test my ASP.Net app"

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to get ahold of the frame with Watin?

```
var frame = browser.Frame(iframeId); // this would return the frame given an id.
```